# C: How can I store an unknown number of inputs using scanf so that each word of the input is stored in a different variable?

Tags: c

So far i have:

```
    char r[4][10];

    printf("Enter an option: \n");
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %s", r[0],r[1],r[2], r[3], r[4]);
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]);
```

This works as long as 5 inputs are given. Right now if you type less then 5 inputs and hit enter the program continues to ask for input until it has all 5 values but I want the scanf to stop and the program to continue if less then 5 inputs are entered.

Comment: This is what loops are for: read in one value at a time and increment a counter.

Comment: Use gets to get the line.  In a loop, use strtok (or strtok_s) to split the line and then sscanf to read each number.  Look up the man pages or help on these functions.

Comment: @cup: never, ever use `gets()`; pretend it never existed!

Comment: @cup Not joking. avoid `gets()` like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

You'll do best to read a line with `fgets()` and parse it with `sscanf()`.  If there will be no more than 5 words on a line:

```
char r[5][10];
char line[4096];

printf("Enter an option: \n");
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
{
    int num = sscanf(line, "%9s %9s %9s %9s %9s", r[0],r[1],r[2], r[3], r[4]);
    for (int i = num; i < 5; i++)
        r[i][0] = '\0';
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]);
}
```

Note that you only had `r[4][10]` but were using subscript 4 — bad move.

A better way to handle it would be a loop that scans over the line, reading a word at a time until there is no more space in the array or no more words in the line.  It's a little trickier, though.